# Using maven versions plugin to handle dependency version

Tags: java, maven, version, pom.xml

I have the a project pom and a parent pom. The parent pom defines a dependency as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycode/groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My project pom inherits the parent and defines the dependency.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>au.com.truelocal</groupId>
    <artifactId>truelocal-parent</artifactId>
    <version>develop</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycode</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I used to build with Maven this way without issue.

I now want to start having a different version in parent, common and project.

I am going to use the maven versions plugin to set my version.

I am setting the parent version and version successfully however, maven keeps looking for the wrong version of common.  E.g. if my project is building as version 1.0.0-4 then it looks for common-1.0.0-4 but I actually need it to get the latest version of common instead which could be for example 1.0.0-23.

Can i use the versions plugin to adjust my dependency version?  How do I make it only apply to common and not other dependencies I may have?

Answer (score 0):

`mvn versions:set` (I guess this is what you've done) sets the version of your project, respectively the project versions which are part of a multi module project.

It doesn't touch the versions of the dependencies, either they are configured in a parent pom within `<dependencyManagement>` or within `<dependencies>`.

You can adjust the dependency versions by several ways: `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` , `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` , `mvn versions:use-latest-snapshots`.

Use `mvn versions:help` or `mvn versions:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=use-latest-snapshots` to get more informations.